# VirtualBox on OS X Server cannot ping guest OS network adapter IS bridged

Tags: macos, virtualbox, ping, osx-server

I have a Mac OS X server running one instance of Windows 7 x64 Pro. The network adapter is in bridge mode, my router is assigning the proper IP address according to the mac of the VM through the DHCP configuration but I cannot ping the ip of the virtual machine even from the Host OS...

Any idea on shat is the problem? Is this Mac OS X Server related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with XP.  Turned out that the windows (guest) firewall was blocking the pings.
Turning off the firewall (briefly) allowed the ping to work.